# Git -- is there a list of all possible errors somewhere on the internet?

Tags: c++, git

I am invoking the posix `popen` function on many git commands quite frequently in my application.

I am parsing the git output and want to check if there is an error, expected or not.

Is there an exhaustive list somewhere on the internet which contains all the possible error strings that git can return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to find out in the Git Source Code: https://github.com/git/git

But in general, you should test whether or not there was an error via the command return code, which is 0 if there was no error and nonzero when there was an error (so you don't need to parse the output to detect an error).